# IndexError: index 720 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 720

Tags: python, cross-validation

With the following code, I am trying to make cross-validation, splitting into k = 5 folds, and then picking one of those for validation, and the remaining for training.

```
# size of the different sets:
# features (800,2)
# labels (800,)

lambdaValues = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
nFolds = 5
foldSize = int(len(features)/nFolds)

for i in range(len(lambdaValues)):
    for ii in range(0, len(features), foldSize):
        pick_training = np.array(features)
        pick_validation = np.zeros((foldSize, 2))
        training_labels = labels
        validation_labels = np.zeros((foldSize, 2))
        k = ii
        # perform k-fold split (here a five-fold split)
        for n in range(foldSize):
            pick_validation[n] = pick_training[k]
            validation_labels[n] = training_labels[k]
            pick_training = np.delete(pick_training, k, axis=0)
            training_labels = np.delete(training_labels, k, axis=0)
            k+=1
        # do something (cross-validate) 
        # do something (cross-validate)
        # do something (cross-validate)

        print(pick_training.shape) # expected size (160, 2)
        print(pick_validation.shape) # expected size (640, 2)
```

However, right now when I run it (still missing some actual computations) I get the following error:

[image]

I cant quiet understand why this happens, as the values of `n`, `k` are correct, and the size of `pick_validation` is (160,2) and `pick_training` is (640,2).

Can anyone hint to me why it would say that index 720 is out of bounds? (given the sizes of the arrays above where neither is of size 720).

Comment: Because the indices are from 0 to 719.

Comment: @Guy but I do not get how the indices can be in that range, when the sizes of the arrays respectively are (160,2) and (800,2)? If this was indeed the case, the array size would be (720,2) for the `pick_training` instance.

Comment: `pick_validation` or `pick_training` has size of 720. My guess is `features` is not what you think it is.

Comment: @Guy The problem seem to be that when I update `pick_training` and `training_labels` (below), I keep deleting the row selected, which makes the array smaller in size. At the last iteration where my `k = 640`, I can iterate 80 times, up to `k = 719`, but then when I try to index 720, it no longer exists, cause I removed 80 elements from the array until that point. Is there a smarter way to fix that from happening?

Comment: Remove the deletion, it doesn't seem to serve any purpose.

Comment: @Guy The idea is that I want `pick_training` to contain exactly 640 indices, by removing the part that I extract to the `pick_validation` fold. So if I do not use delete, I would have the entire data set left?